# Alexa simulator does not recognise number as slot value

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, slot

this is my utterance - "when do the may holidays start for boarders in 2018", 
which "may" and "2018" are my required slot values. However alexa is not picking up "2018" as a slot value already fulfilled but only "may" as fulfilled. i realised this is only happening because 2018 is a number. is there anyway to go around this?
See screenshot in the link

[image: Alexa simulator screenshot]

Comment: If the number is a date per your example 2018, why not utilize AMAZON.DATE which has an expected result of 2018

Comment: Also, would be helpful for you to read through article on dialog management for multiple slot utterences for fulfillment. https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/44dd83f4-4842-40c5-91f8-3868b9f4608c/using-dialog-management-to-capture-a-and-b-or-c-slots

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER`. I think you're typing your request in the Alexa simulator, so maybe Alexa is not able to recognize that as a year. But when a user **SAYS(voice)** the content in the screenshot above, Alexa interprets it as:

> When do the may holidays start for boarders in two thousand eighteen

Then the built-in slot `AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER` will convert `two thousand eighteen` to `2018` automatically and `2018` will be available to you to use it in your code.

Alternatively, you can use `AMAZON.DATE`, but this didn't recognize my years properly sometimes. So, for year recognition, I had to ignore `AMAZON.DATE`.